# $\int_{|z| = r} |f_n(z)|^2 dz \leq1$ implies $f_n$ is normal

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> Suppose that for each $n$ the function $f_n$ is analytic in the open unit disk, $|f_n(0)| ≤ 1$,
> and for each $r < 1$ satisfies

$$\int_{|z| = r} |f_n(z)|^2 |dz| \leq 1$$

Show that every subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ has a further subsequence which converges to a finite
analytic function uniformly on each compact subset of the open unit disk.

I know that by Montel's Theorem it suffices to show that $f_n$ are locally bounded. However, I am not really sure what to do with the hypothesis.

Comment: The maximum principle may be useful here.

Comment: *Hint.* for each $0<s<r<$ and $|z|\leq s$, $$|f_n(z)|^2=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{f_n(\xi)^2}{\xi-z}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\right|\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|\xi|=r}\frac{|f_n(\xi)|^2}{r-s}\,|\mathrm{d}\xi|. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee, with this approach is seems like the $|f_n(0)| \leq 1$ is superfluous?

Comment: Indeed it seems like so. Perhaps the author might have had another approach in his/her mind?